# How to access a singleton service from a custom class decorator

Tags: angular

Is it possible to access a singleton service from a decorator function? i know decorator is run at build time. just wondering if there is a way. Im trying make a library and use the decorators syntax as the api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: probably not, decorators are applied before a class is initialized and before Angular application is initialized. check [Implementing custom component decorator in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d)

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: short answer: no. Longer answer: noooooooo